# Getting ClassNotFoundException while trying to connect mysql with jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp, jdbc

I have a JSP that looks like this

```
<%
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","root"); 

Statement st= con.createStatement(); 

ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from example");
.
.
.
%>
```

When i request the jsp I get this error:

HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:911)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:840)
org.apache.jsp.test_jsp._jspService(test_jsp.java:95)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:126)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
org.apache.jsp.test_jsp._jspService(test_jsp.java:69)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.26 logs.

Answer (score 3):

simply put the **mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar** file in the **WEB-INF/lib** of your directory present inside webapps of tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

add mysql  `mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin` jar to your class path.

Comment: i have added them but in vain

Comment: <%
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","mypc"); 

Statement st= con.createStatement(); 

ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from example");
.
.
.%>

Comment: it is showing 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /test1.jsp at line 13
and line no. 13 is
13: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

plz help its urgent.

Comment: did u try to recompile and re-deploy everything after making the classpath addition ? cause your problem really looks so simple as just a class not found

Comment: Are there any guides or instructions published on how to "download add mysql connector to jasper studio"?  It seems amazing that they would ship with no DB connectors, and then give zero instructions on how to add them.